# Amana furnace discharge vent seems clogged

Tags: hvac, heating

My furnace starts out very slowly trying to put out hot air maybe 2 to 3 hours. I think maybe my discharge vent may be clogged but its on a slippery roof and about 30 foot of PVC so how would I clean it or check it out?

Comment: Please revise your post to eliminate the SCREAMING CAPS.

Comment: Nice little helper for [case conversion](https://convertcase.net/).

Comment: Have someone come in with a borescope, basically a camera on a flexible, steerable shaft, and take a look for any obstructions.

Comment: Thanks but was looking for a cost savings way otherwise I would just call an HVAC contractor

Comment: Turn the furnace off, then try pulling a vacuum on the discharge line with a shopvac?

Comment: Thanks but there are no flashing codes, it just stays solid red?

Comment: Has no one ever seen a new system that was undersized? Dang. I have seen this several times from “top of the line” systems that the contractor undersized. Unfortunately the owners signed the contracts to install the new high efficiency equipment that did not heat as well this sounds like what I have seen several times.

Answer (score 0):

The models I have installed have flow or pressure sensors that shutdown the fire box if an obstruction is detected. The control board may have some LED’s that show an abnormal condition. Usually to access the board an access cover needs to be opened, this has a switch that kills power, normally pulling out the plunger will energize the electronics, run the system and look for blinking LED’s or a series of LED’s these are how many units tell us something is wrong.

Comment: No flashing light (no codes) Maybe I'll go ahead and stuff a shop vac although it is about 30ft long also am thinking of by passing and running a new one out a near by window for a while with the garage door open

Comment: Your system may be operating properly, hard to tell , I have installed a few systems and have been called to fix things that I Could not find a problem , you say it starts slow , well what size home and what size or btu heater I have seen DIY furnaces at 80k btu that should have had a 150k at minimum. My shop had a 125k forced gas heater not enough info I know!!! But if you have no errors and the system is working it may just be two small to provide the level of comfort you want!

Comment: I just went out to the garage and blew/sucked on both the vacuum switches and wiggled a couple of wires on them, also checked the the over flow/condensation and theirs no back up, been working for 15 minutes now and in that short of time really heated the cabin up, crossing my fingers. my cabin is 2400 sf with 24ft ceilings in the great room also at 5500 ft in the sierra's. really appreciate your input Thanks John

Comment: A plugged or blocked switch might cause a problem but an upvote or accepted answer may help others find a similar solution.